# :hover feature , How to approach the same result as js code by using css

Tags: css

If I have a **table**:

```
<table border="1" id="my_table">
    <tr>
        <td> data-1</td>
        <td> data-1</td>
        <td> data-1</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td> data-2</td>
        <td> data-2</td>
        <td> data-2</td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

I would like to add hover background for **each column** or the row, that's for **each** `<td>` of the hovered row, I can do this by using **javascript** like below:

```
 $('#my_table tr').hover(function() {
    $(this).children('td').css('background-color', '#330099');
  }, function() {
    $(this).children('td').css('background-color', '');
  });
```

The above **js** code working nicely, my question is how to use **CSS** to approach the same result?

What I tried is

```
tr > td:hover{
    background-color: #330099;
}
```

but the above code **only change one** `<td>`'s background color instead of all `<td>`s' of the row. How to get rid of this?

My code is [here on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bptpq/1/).

**------------------------------------By The Way-----------------------------------**

**Please DO NOT** suggest me to just use :

```
tr:hover{background-color: #440099}
```

I know this is working, but for my special need, I would prefer to change all `<td>`s' background color when mouse hover a certain row, just like what the js code did.

Because I have set my `<td>` background which will hide the `tr:hover` feature behind the back, so, I have to change `<td>`'s background explicitly. (this is not in my sample code above though)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
tr:hover td {background-color: #440099;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mM2Ep/

Hope that helps :)

Comment: I just wonder why I did not have this code came up to my mind. Hey! Thank you! (wait 10 min, then I can accept your answer)